# Mobile iDEAL payments not being captured

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been struggling with this issue for some time now. Even created a support ticket at my Devs PayPal portal, but even the devs seem to not know what exactly is going wrong. Therefor, I'm asking it here, hoping someone can help me.

**The issue:** I have a website where people have to check out using iDEAL. To process these iDEAL payments, I use PayPal. Everything works great on desktop, but for some reason, the payments are not being captured when I use my iPhone to pay. I even checked it on different devices, but the issue remains.

**What happens when I use my dekstop to pay:** after selecting the desired bank, I get redirected to the payment page of my bank. I scan the QR code, make the payment, and get redirected to my own website where I store everything in the DB / show success message. The money has been taken out of my bank and added to my PayPal account. (the payment has been captured)

**What happens when I use my phone to pay:** after selecting the desired bank, I get redirected to the App to make the payment. Once done so, I get redirected to a 'Thank you' page from PayPal themselfs. The money has been taken out of my bank account, but NOT added to my PayPal account, instead it gone missing (and probably gets refunded by PayPal). - the payment has NOT been captured.

The above is whenever I'm not using the sandbox. However, I'm in the sandbox, the same thing happens: desktop payments are being captured, mobile payments are NOT being captured.

When I check the API calls in my PayPal Dev dashboard, I can see when I'm paying via mobile that the order has been created, but never captured. But the order is being created and captured when I use my desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

**This is the part of my code**

```
// CREATE GLOBAL VARS
var invoice_id = '<?php echo $db_invoice_id; ?>';

function submit_database(transaction_id, transaction_amount, transaction_status) {
    
    // DEBUG                                                
    console.log('---BELOW PAYPAL FUNCTION---');
    console.log(invoice_id);
    console.log(transaction_id);
    console.log(transaction_amount);
    console.log(transaction_status);
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/data/betalingen/herinnering/",
        data: {invoice_id: invoice_id, transaction_id: transaction_id, transaction_amount: transaction_amount, transaction_status: transaction_status},
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   start_processingIDEALPayment(data,textStatus,jqXHR);    }
    });
    
    function start_processingIDEALPayment(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {  
        // DEBUG
        //alert(data);
        console.log(data);
        
        if (data == 'success') {
            $('.access-purchase .actions').hide();
            $('.access-purchase .content-inner .description').removeClass('alert-danger');
            $('.access-purchase .content-inner .description').addClass('alert-success');
            $('.access-purchase .content-inner .description').html('<i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> Wij hebben je betaling succesvol ontvangen. De pagina wordt ieder moment ververst, waarna je toegang zult hebben tot de stream.');
        
            setTimeout(function (){
                //Reload page 
                location.reload();
            }, 5000);
        }
        

    }
     
}

paypal.PaymentFields({
  fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.IDEAL,
  fields: {
    // PREFILL NAME FIELD
    name: {
      value: "<?pho echo $db_name; ?>",
    },
    
  }
})
.render("#ideal-fields");

paypal.Buttons({
      fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.IDEAL,
      style: { label: "pay", },
      
      createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
                    
             "purchase_units": [{
                "amount": {
                  "currency_code": "EUR",
                  "value": "<?php echo $next_amount_to_pay; ?>",
                  "breakdown": {
                    "item_total": {
                      "currency_code": "EUR",
                      "value": "<?php echo $next_amount_to_pay; ?>"
                    }
                  }
                }, 
                "items": [
                  {
                    "name": "Betaling voor factuur: #<?php echo $db_invoice_id; ?>",
                    "unit_amount": {
                      "currency_code": "EUR",
                      "value": "<?php echo $next_amount_to_pay; ?>"
                    },
                    "quantity": "1"
                  },
                ],
                
              }]
          });
        },
                                                        
        
    onApprove(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

            
            // DEBUG
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
            
            // CREATE VARS
            var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                                                                    
            var transaction_id = transaction.id;
            var transaction_amount = transaction.amount.value;
            var transaction_status = transaction.status;
            
            // DEBUG
            console.log(transaction_id);
            console.log(transaction_amount);
            console.log(transaction_status);

        
            // SUBMIT TO DB
            submit_database(transaction_id, transaction_amount, transaction_status);
            
            // SHOW MESSAGE TO USER
            $('.box.invoice-payment').hide(); // HIDE PAYMENT FORM
            $('#openPaymentHandler').hide(); // HIDE PAYMENT FORM
            
            $('#payment-callback').removeClass('alert-danger');
            $('#payment-callback').addClass('alert-success');
            $('#payment-callback').html('<i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> Wij hebben je betaling in goede orde ontvangen.');
            $('#payment-callback').show();
            
            setTimeout(function (){
                //Reload page 
                location.reload();
            }, 3500);
                                                                
        });
      
    },
  
  onCancel(data, actions) { 
        // CANCELED
        //DEBUG
        console.log(`Order Canceled - ID: ${data.orderID}`);    
        
        var transaction_id = data.orderID;
        var transaction_amount = '0.00';
        var transaction_status = 'cancelled';
        
        // SUBMIT TO DB
        submit_database(transaction_id, transaction_amount, transaction_status);
        
        // SHOW MESSAGE TO USER
        $('#payment-callback').removeClass('alert-success');
        $('#payment-callback').addClass('alert-danger');
        $('#payment-callback').html('<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark"></i> De betaling is afgebroken of mislukt.');
        $('#payment-callback').show();
    },
     
    onError(err) { 
        // ERROR
        // DEBUG 
        console.error(err);
        
        if (err == 'Error: Detected popup close') {
            var errorMsg = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark"></i> De betaling is mislukt, omdat het betaalvenster is afgesloten.';
        } else {
            var errorMsg = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark"></i> De betaling is afgebroken of mislukt.';
        }
    
        // SHOW MESSAGE TO USER
        $('#payment-callback').removeClass('alert-success');
        $('#payment-callback').addClass('alert-danger');
        $('#payment-callback').html(errorMsg);
        $('#payment-callback').show();
        
        alert(err);
    },
    
    
  
}).render("#ideal-btn");
```

Comment: Is onApprove being called on mobile, or not? Anyway you should not be using the client-side actions.order.create / .capture function and then writing to a database after the fact. The client-side functions are only for very simple use cases, not this. Server-side creation and capture with the /v2/checkout/orders API should be done, here is the button approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: @PrestonPHX the onApprove is not being called on mobile, for whatever given reason. I’ll look into the link you posted. I really only need the iDEAL payment option, none else.

Comment: You already have code for rendering a single funding source. Since you're already doing it, you don't need information on that, but the guide for iDEAL is at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/apm/ideal/ and in addition to this it explains how to set up webhooks and has an option for redirect-based Orders API integrations (not using the JS SDK for approval) which apparently may work better for you from mobile.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I configured to be server-sided now. However, I'm still facing the same exact issue. iDEAL payment via mobile are not being captured..

Comment: An approved webhook event can be used to then do a capture. The guide explains this

Answer (score 0):

It seems the 2.2.0 update fixes this.
I had the same issue (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ideal-payment-got-cancelled-at-user-side-no-entry-at-my-side/), and this update from 17 July 2023 seems to fix it.
Just tried ordering from my Android phone, which works now.